# Can we prove $\sum_{i=1}^m \frac{1}{t_i +1} \ge \sum_{i=1}^m \frac{1}{\lambda_i +1}$ or not?

Tags: inequality

Let $t_1,\dots,t_m \ge 0$, and $\lambda_1, \dots, \lambda_m \ge 0$. Suppose
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
& t_1 + \dots + t_m = m(\lambda_1 + \dots + \lambda_m), \\
& t_1 \times \dots \times t_m \leq \lambda_1 \times \dots \times \lambda_m.
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
Can we prove the following inequality:
\begin{equation}
\sum_{i=1}^m \frac{1}{t_i +1} \ge \sum_{i=1}^m \frac{1}{\lambda_i +1}.
\end{equation}
I am stuck for a long time and have tried many methods, but have no idea at all. Can anyone prove it or provide a counterexample? Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: How is this linear algebra?

Comment: fine, I edited it.

Comment: the thing is close to majorization theory related to linear algebra in a way.

Comment: @ToniMhax Thanks for the hint !

Comment: maybe $t_1+t_2=\lambda_1+\lambda_2$ yields the inequality when $m=2$. etc

Comment: @ToniMhax, I agree. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A preliminary calculation gives the following counterexample, 
$$m=2,t_1=\frac{3+\sqrt 7}{2}, t_2=\frac{3-\sqrt 7}{2}, \lambda_1=1,\lambda_2=\frac{1}{2}.$$
You can double check if it is indeed a counterexample or there is a mistake in my calculation.

Comment: It seems correct, but I am very curious that how did you find this counterexample? Anyway, thank you very much.

Comment: Actually, it should not be hard to check that under your conditions, the inequality is true if and only if $\lambda_1 \lambda_2\ge 1$. From this, it should be easy to get a counterexample.

Answer (score 1):

The sum constraint may be the wrong one if $t_1=4$ and $t_2=0$, $\lambda_1=1.9$, $\lambda_2=0.1$,  $\begin{equation}
\sum_{i=1}^2 \frac{1}{t_i +1}=1.2 \le \sum_{i=1}^2 \frac{1}{\lambda_i +1}\approx 1.25
\end{equation}$